# Copy pathname from Finder with tilde (~/) instead of absolute home directory

Tags: mac, finder, path

Since OS X El Capitan, right-clicking on a file in Finder while pressing "Option" shows a menu function *Copy "File.txt" as Pathname*.

I wonder if I can replace the absolute path of the home directory so that I get the tilde as in

```
~/Documents/File.txt
```

instead of

```
/Users/My-User-Alias/Documents/File.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

No.  The ~ substitution is a shell construct.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would still be very useful for sev. actions. Wonder if there is no workaround (can't see that deep into macOS).
Appreciate any help!